# How can I formulate the function solution?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```js
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
t = []
c = []
for(i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
   function solution(){
       t = Math.pow(x, 2)
       c = t[i]++
    return c
   } 
}
```

The function needs to:

1. Count the squares of the array numbers
2. Then to get sum of squared (I am not sure if I wrote it correct, LOL) numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var result = [1, 2, 3, 4].map(n => Math.pow(n, 2)).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const result = [1, 2, 3, 4].map(n => n ** 2).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);

console.log(result);
```

You can also use `**` operator which is faster than `Math.pow()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators